# Using osmnx to download UK boundary produces distorted outline of the country

Tags: openstreetmap, osmnx

I am using the following code to download country boundaries with `osmnx`:

```py
country = ox.geocode_to_gdf(['United Kingdom'])
ax = ox.project_gdf(country).plot()
```

This produces a distorted outline of the `United Kingdom` but seems to work fine with other countries.

[image: Distorted UK outline]

Comment: Not all relations in OSM necessarily have sorted members. Sometimes it depends on the type of relation if sorting is a requirement. So in your case it might be necessary to perform sorting yourself.

Comment: What do you mean by distorted? What exactly does it look like? What did you expect to see? Images would help illustrate.

Comment: I have added an image

Comment: I see now that this apparent distortion is because the downloaded relation includes coastal waters. Is there an argument that can be passed in with ox.geocode_to_gdf(['United Kingdom']) that will exclude coastal waters? I have tried using boundary='administrative' but this generates an error

Comment: OSMnx simply downloads data from OpenStreetMap. If the boundary without coastal waters exists on OSM itself, you can download it.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the UK borders from Nominatim instead as shown in [the JsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/x0jpnwsy/):

[image: United Kingdom borders on an OpenStreetMap]

And if you wish less border details, append the [&polygon_threshold=0.1](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/api/Search/#parameters) parameter to the Nominatim `url` in my Javascript code:

```js
'use strict';

function processNominatimReply(data) {
  data.features.forEach(function(feature) {
    bordersGroup.addData(feature);
  });

  var bbox = data.features[0].bbox;
  var topLeft = L.latLng(bbox[1], bbox[0]);
  var bottomRight = L.latLng(bbox[3], bbox[2]);
  var countryBounds = L.latLngBounds(topLeft, bottomRight);

  var name = data.features[0].properties.display_name;
  var tooltip = L.tooltip()
    .setLatLng(countryBounds.getCenter())
    .setContent(name)
    .addTo(namesGroup);

  myMap.flyToBounds(countryBounds);
}

function sendNominatimRequest(countryCode) {
  var url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search' +
      '?polygon_geojson=1' +
      '&format=geojson' +
      '&country=' + countryCode;

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.onload = function() {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
      var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
      processNominatimReply(data);
    }
  };
  request.send();
}

var startPosition = [51.5072, 0.1276];
var myMap = L.map('myMap').setView(startPosition, 14);
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(myMap);

var namesGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(myMap);
var bordersGroup = L.geoJSON().addTo(myMap);

var overlays = {
  'Show country names': namesGroup,
  'Show country borders': bordersGroup
};

L.control.layers(null, overlays, {
  collapsed: false
}).addTo(myMap);

sendNominatimRequest('uk');
```

```css
html, body { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#myMap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1/dist/leaflet.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1/dist/leaflet-src.min.js"></script>

<div id="myMap"></div>
```